# JPA executeUpdate() does not update database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

We are using JPA NameQueries for doing an update operation with executeUpdate(). The method returns 1 which I am inferring that the update was successful but the database is not updated.

Can someone help understand what is getting updated and what can I do to get the update on the database?

Thanks

Comment: How does your UPDATE statement look like?

Comment: Bro, do you even commit?